# Using attrs decorators in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting, python-attrs

I have the following *attrs* class:

```py
from attrs import define, field

@define
class Foo:
    bar: int = field()
    
    @bar.validator
    def check(self, attribute, value):
        ...
```

It works normally at runtime, as expected:

```
lorem = Foo(42)  # Fine
ipsum = Foo('')  # Expected type 'int', got 'str' instead
```

However, PyCharm is giving me a warning about `@bar.validator` (this is [a known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30209)):

```
Unresolved attribute reference 'validator' for class 'int'
```

I don't want to define module-level functions, nor can I stuff everything into `lambda`s. What other (Pythonic) choices do I have?

Comment: You can just ignore the pycharm's warning or disabled it altogether. It won't really affect your program.

Comment: @YoshikageKira I know I can do that, but I also have some inexplicable need of doing things correctly. That said, this problem is more of satisfying myself as a programmer rather than satisfying PyCharm.

Comment: This is right way afaik. I personally rely more on mypy rather than PyCharm since Pycharm can either miss a lot of things or just have bugs.

Comment: You could use attrs post init and check if variables are set correctly. It is not preferred way by it satisfies pycharm.

Comment: Another option is to ditch attrs and use Pydantic which does data type validation ootb if data validation is really that important to you. No complains from PyCharm afaik.

Comment: @YoshikageKira I'm using `.validator` only as an example. The actual use case doesn't, but it does use other decorators. If I recall correctly, Pydantic does a lot of runtime parsing and therefore will unnecessarily affect performance.

Comment: Then this whole question is just pointless.